# Collab error:ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python

I am runnig the following comand `!pip install bert-tensorflow natural-questions`, and it gives me the error :

```
Collecting bert-tensorflow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/16/0f9376af49c6adcfbaf2470a8f500105a74dd803aa54ac0110af445837b5/bert_tensorflow-1.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting natural-questions
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/d7/020da0200e8129c0ae7a1da998c7ff84dd2f3a4660711b2aa39286c67f85/natural_questions-1.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from bert-tensorflow) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from natural-questions) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from natural-questions) (2.11.2)
Collecting wsgiref
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/9e/309259ce8dff8c596e8c26df86dbc4e848b9249fd36797fd60be456f03fc/wsgiref-0.1.2.zip
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am working on google colab.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

---

Try using this, it might work

Answer (score 0):

Error is in installing wsgiref but its already installed in python3. also try using python2 in colab see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with `wsgiref`, which is installed already but `pip` tries to reinstall it.

Try installing 2 libs separately as follows

```
%pip install bert-tensorflow
%pip install --no-dependencies natural-questions
```

Later if you have any issue with any of the dependencies of `natural-questions`, try installing it manually.

For instance for a later issue use

```
%pip install language
```

Answer (score 0):

Now when I am running :

```
python -m language.question_answering.bert_joint.prepare_nq_data \
  --logtostderr \
  --input_jsonl ~/data/nq-train-??.jsonl.gz \
  --output_tfrecord ~/output_dir/nq-train.tfrecords-00000-of-00001 \
  --max_seq_length=512 \
  --include_unknowns=0.02 \
  --vocab_file=bert-joint-baseline/vocab-nq.txt
```

It gives me error :

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'language.question_answering.bert_joint.prepare_nq_data' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'language')
```

before I also run `gsutil cp -R gs://bert-nq/bert-joint-baseline .` without error

Comment: Never post this as an answer

Comment: Thank you so much, I see. But here is  one more problem: now the error is 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'language.question_answering' ' but when I am trying '%pip install language.question_answering' here is the error : 'ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement language.question_answering (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for language.question_answering'